# Air pressure at 500 km under sea level

Tags: pressure, mathematical-physics, earth, planets, gas

Suppose you could drill a well 500 km deep without it closing in on itself, so that essentially you would have a 500 km deep hole in the ground filled with nothing but air. Also, suppose that the air that goes into the hole is imported from another planet so that the height of the Earth's atmosphere is unaffected. Taking into account the compression of air and the changing gravity deeper down etc., how high would the air pressure be at the bottom of the well? Would the air even be gaseous anymore or would it liquidify?

Comment: 500km of air pressure is roughly 500m of water pressure, you can dive on compressed gas at those depths (although not on regular air for physiological reasons) - it's not nearly enough pressure to liquify air at room temperature

Comment: @MartinBeckett, you may have missed seeing the "k" in "km".

Comment: @jameslarge, OP had an air filled hole 500km deep. Water is roughly 1000x as dense as air so simple assumption 500km air = 500m water.

Comment: Uh Oh!  Looks like I missed sseeing the "" in "m".  Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

This is partially covered in a [XKCD:what if?](https://what-if.xkcd.com/153/) and the [cited paper](http://nopr.niscair.res.in/handle/123456789/2506).

In short: Calculations are more than just applying the ideal gas law since the air will heat up depending on the surrounding temperature.
As stated in both "what if?" and the linked paper, if the temperature rises by 30°C per km you get no compression at all.

Given that after about 50 km hole you reach the [earth's mantle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantle_(geology)) with temperatures between 500 and 900 °C according to Wikipedia, i am pretty sure there's no liquid air....